# Minio Java API Client is not returning status response when removing objects from a bucket

Tags: java, spring-boot, minio

I am using the Minio Java API Client to remove objects from a bucket, and the removal process is working fine. However, I am not getting any status response after removing the objects. I have used the following code:

```
Iterable<Result<DeleteError>> results = minioClient.removeObjects(removeObjectsArgs);
long size = results.spliterator().getExactSizeIfKnown();

for (Result<DeleteError> errorResult: results) {
    DeleteError error = errorResult.get();
    System.out.println("Failed to remove '" + error.objectName() + "'. Error:" + error.message());
}
```

I have also tried putting a breakpoint inside the for loop, and it confirmed that I am not getting any Iterable response. I know that the objects are being removed from the bucket, but I need to get a status response to confirm the successful removal.

One possible solution that I have thought of is to delete the objects and then loop through all the objects that were deleted to check if they still exist in the bucket. However, this approach is cumbersome and not ideal.

Can anyone suggest why the removeObjects method is not returning a status response? Are there any other ways to get a status response after removing objects from a bucket using the Minio Java API Client?